# Can not get the list of all dates from a list of tibbles

Tags: r, datetime, for-loop, time-series, nested-tibble

I have a list of tibbles or list columns, each tibble contain a column with dates and the other one temperatures.
I want to get the date in the index located in a vector but what I tried it doesn't work for a  reason that I can't see.
This is my code and results:

```
datetr = as.POSIXct(vector())
for (i in seq_along(dts)){
    datetr=as.POSIXct(dts[[i]][[1]][[stagt[i]]])
}

[1] "2019-11-04 15:18:32 UTC"
```

Where dts is the list of tibbles and stagt is the vector that contains the indexes.

This for-loop save on datetr the one date-time and not 106 values as I expected.
Trying to understand what can be wrong I tried to change manually the indexes and then it works, but I need a list.

```
as.POSIXct(dts[[1]][[1]][[46]])
as.POSIXct(dts[[2]][[1]][[36]])

> as.POSIXct(dts[[1]][[1]][[46]])
[1] "2018-08-07 18:30:31 UTC"
> as.POSIXct(dts[[2]][[1]][[36]])
[1] "2018-08-08 17:46:05 UTC"
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()` and use the [reprex-package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try this:

```
datetr = as.POSIXct(vector())
for (i in seq_along(dts)){
    datetr <- as.POSIXct(c(datetr, dts[[i]][[1]][[stagt[i]]]))
}
```

Comment: Hi Jared. The advice on supplying an MCVE is sound, but it's probably better to supply it in a comment under the question. The reasons for this is that it's not in itself answer material, and that answers are best written for a wide audience, rather than just the question author.

Comment: (I don't know if there is canonical advice on Meta, though I note [mod action on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77033107/revisions). I might have a hunt on Meta myself...)